# investigate build failure with profile

Tags: maven, build, installation

I'm really new to maven but got asked to to build a .ear. Can you guys tell me where to start my investigation for the following build failure ? Thank you !

p.s. for some reason the following directory or file does not exist so I can't look there: /home/COMPANY/guillaume.caille/workspace/PRODUCT-war-1.3.1.5/target/surefire-reports

-Guillaume

```
COMPANY\guillaume.caille@LAPMTL-092:~/workspace/PRODUCT-war-1.3.1.5> mvn -Pxyz clean 

install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PRODUCT-war
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting directory /home/COMPANY/guillaume.caille/workspace/PRODUCT-war-1.3.1.5/target
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 51 source files to /home/COMPANY/guillaume.caille/workspace/PRODUCT-war-1.3.1.5/target/classes
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/COMPANY/guillaume.caille/workspace/PRODUCT-war-1.3.1.5/target/test-classes
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/COMPANY/guillaume.caille/workspace/PRODUCT-war-1.3.1.5/target/surefire-reports
/bin/sh: go: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `go'
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Unable to create test class 'COMPANY.PRODUCT.util.productFormHelperTest'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COMPANY.PRODUCT.util.productFormHelperTest not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/tmp/surefirebooterv8qbfy.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}; nested exception is org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Unable to create test class 'COMPANY.PRODUCT.util.productFormHelperTest'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COMPANY.PRODUCT.util.productFormHelperTest not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/tmp/surefirebooterv8qbfy.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Unable to create test class 'COMPANY.PRODUCT.util.productFormHelperTest'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COMPANY.PRODUCT.util.productFormHelperTest not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/tmp/surefirebooterv8qbfy.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COMPANY.PRODUCT.util.productFormHelperTest not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/tmp/surefirebooterv8qbfy.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:87)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.createSuiteFromDefinition(Surefire.java:209)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:156)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.13)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/COMPANY/guillaume.caille/workspace/PRODUCT-war-1.3.1.5/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 19 16:21:34 GMT-04:00 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 69M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPANY\guillaume.caille@LAPMTL-092:~/workspace/PRODUCT-war-1.3.1.5>
```

Comment: You have a profile named "clean"?

Comment: Can you show us your test code and maybe your pom?

Comment: here is the pom file 
http://pastebin.com/X4TyNXj9
I don't know yet how to get the test code.

Comment: Can you put this in the actual question?